# node js encrypt values by public key error TypeError: Data must be a buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have a back end service that works with payment gateway, for this purpose I need to encrypt a few parameters. I'm using **crypto** library but in signing value that contains sum of values let `value = a+b+c+d` its returns an error message like below :

> TypeError: Data must be a buffer
>       at Sign.sign (crypto.js:331:26)

this is my function for encrypting

```
const sign = (value) => {
    let sign = crypto.createSign('SHA1');
    sign.update(Buffer.from(value), 'utf8');
    return sign.sign(PrivateKey, 'base64');
}
```

which my PrivateKey is something like this 123

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code which uses the sign function.

Comment: which version of nodejs?

Comment: @VenkatChaitanyaSama Im just calling method to return encrypted in the console.log(sign(value))

Comment: @Cr. Im using v8.9.4

Comment: if it's a number, try `Buffer.from(String(value))`

Answer (score 0):

> which my PrivateKey is something like this 123

Your `PrivateKey` is wrong. Execute the following command to generate PrivateKey `openssl genrsa  -out privkey.pem 1024`.

```
 let pem = fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem');
 let PrivateKey = pem.toString('ascii');
```

`crypto` module description is

> The crypto module provides cryptographic functionality that includes a set of wrappers for OpenSSL's hash, HMAC, cipher, decipher, sign, and verify functions.

Comment: I got my private key from payment gateway company, which is 3 digit numbers                                                                                                         `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
          123
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: After using  yours way i receive an error like `Error: error:0906D064:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad base64 decode
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:331:26)
`

Comment: Your code work fine on me when I replace `PrivateKey `, And this error also `PRIVATE KEY` file error, are you use openssl generate `PRIVATE KEY`?

Comment: I dont generated this PrivateKey . 
I got my private key from payment gateway company which theirs documents.

Comment: my corect key is   `-------BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICeAIBADANBgksdsdsdqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmIwggJeAgEAAosdsdsdsdGBAPaKmgam2CYJ7iC03Hkksdp9H70T5d
v026YF2FBU0sdsddtcqp0PJdssdxv2AjPejrKNkcneb7kQ+Qq8Fo+pzIIvDDjxr5aEsB3nFKUDpS0sdsMNXcJht7
PHvznvZV
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`  format